# How to use Eigen in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, eigen

I read the documentation of [Eigen installation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html). As per the documentation, only header files need to be referred in your project. As shown in the screenshot below, I included the path of the Eigen in my include directories, but the program does not recognize Eigen.

[image]

**Sample Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m(0, 0) = 3;
    m(1, 0) = 2.5;
    m(0, 1) = -1;
    m(1, 1) = m(1, 0) + m(0, 1);
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

**How do I correctly include the Eigen into my C++ project?**

Comment: I'd guess you need to add one directory above the one you've added (i.e. remove `Eigen` from the end of the path)

Comment: Verify that the path makes sense. Is there an `Eigen\Eigen` folder containing a file named `Dense`?

Comment: Consider use of some package manager. vcpkg should work fine with MSVC projects. I think there is some example for Eigent and vcpkg (google it).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You added `path/to/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen` to your include path, but then you include the header `Eigen/Dense`, so this looks for `path/to/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/Eigen/Dense`. That's one `Eigen` too many.

Set the include path to `path/to/eigen-3.4.0` instead.

(Don't be tempted to modify the include to `#include <Dense>` instead. It might cause Eigen to be unable to find its own headers, and can also easily lead to naming conflicts.)